# How do I remove the divider from a listview on android?

Tags: android, android-listview, divider

I'm developing a app that have a `Listview`, and the items from list already have a style I don't need the divider.

How do I set as hidden or remove the divider from the `ListView`?

Comment: do the items need to be clickable?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can try `android:divider="@null"`.

Comment: And in code it would be `listView.setDivider(null);`

Answer (score 14):

There are different ways to achieve this, but I'm not sure which one is the best (I don't even know is there is a best way). I know at least 2 different ways to do this in a ListView:

**1. Set divider to null:**

1.1. Programmatically

```
yourListView.setDivider(null);
```

1.2. XML

```
android:divider="@null" (this goes inside your ListView element)
```

**2. Set divider to transparent and set its height to 0 to avoid adding space between listview elements:**

2.1. Programmatically:

```
yourListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
yourListView.setDividerHeight(0);
```

2.2. XML

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

to your ListView

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/list_of_f"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:divider="@null"
  android:dividerHeight="0dp"
  android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
```