# how to hide the black lines betwen my ListView rows'

Tags: android

Hey how can i hide the dark line on the ground of my row in the listView.
Or to make the line smaller is also ok. Thank you all.

[image]

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="3dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="348dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="153dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
```

Comment: share the layout xml ... that is generating the view

Comment: Duplicate:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914477/how-do-i-remove-lines-between-listviews-on-android :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163200/how-do-i-remove-the-divider-from-a-listview-on-android :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081514/remove-listview-separatorin-the-xml-layout-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
//Hide the divider
getListView().setDivider(null);

//set the divider height
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```

Or, if you want to do it in XML:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Here is the [Developer Notes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Also check the other threada about this problem:
[How do I remove lines between ListViews on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914477/how-do-i-remove-lines-between-listviews-on-android)

Comment: Glad i could help :)